# Thunderbird opening links in Chrome starts a new version!

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird

Chrome is set to my default browser. I am on 15.10. When I click on a link in TB it opens a second version of chrome...but does not go to the link page! If I make FF the default or Chromium the default browser, it works correctly. What am I missing?